# Can I use System.Drawing Via MVC Controller/View in my Razor .NET Core C# website?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have MVC Controller and Views added to my Razor .NET Core C# web application.

It handles PayPal payments but I am thinking could I use this Controller with a View to upload and manipulate images using System.Drawing?
(System.Drawing does not work in Razor Core website)

I have many examples in MVC I have created to manipulate images. Just can't seem to get anything working for my new Razor Core .NET C# website.

To give more insight into my problem I have included the code I am working on below in my website that shows where I ran into the need for Image manipulation. The code uploads a file/image no problem. It is still barebones with no validation but any attempt to manipulate the file as Image before upload fails.

I was thinking if I have an MVC Controller and a View inside of Razor applications, that it would allow all the options that System.Drawing provides. I have spent some considerable time browsing thru existing answers on SO, my favorite problem solver.

```
namespace DaBamba.Pages.YourDances
{
    public class UploadFileModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment _environment;
        public UploadFileModel(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment environment)
        {
            _environment = environment;
        }
        [BindProperty]
        public IFormFile Upload { get; set; }
        public async Task OnPostAsync()
        {

            var file = "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\DaBamba\\wwwroot\\images\\DanceImages\\" + Upload.FileName;

            using var fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create);
          
            //RESIZE IMAGE HERE

            await Upload.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at `SixLabors.ImageSharp` library https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp

Comment: In ASP.NET Core, you can't directly use System.Drawing in .NET Core Razor applications due to platform compatibility constraintsSystem and drawing is not recommended for image processing due to its limitations and security concerns. 

Instead, you can try few alternative approaches to achieve image manipulation.

Comment: @Etienne Charland, SixLabors.ImageSharp would work but the license is $80 a month. My project is not for profit and I can't afford that price.

Comment: @JustJohn "For-profit company/individual with more than 1M USD annual gross revenue you must purchase a Six Labors Commercial License" You're not making 1M USD? You're fine.

Answer (score 0):

> I have MVC Controller and Views added to my Razor .NET Core C# web
> application.
>
> It handles PayPal payments but I am thinking could I use this
> Controller with a View to upload and manipulate images using
> System.Drawing? (System.Drawing does not work in Razor Core website)

Yeah, you are right, as said in comment, in `ASP.NET Core` or in razor page application, you can't directly use System.Drawing due to platform compatibility constraints. Also System and drawing is not recommended for image processing due to its limitations and security concerns.

`System.Drawing` is not usable in ASP.NET Core because, it relies heavily on the GDI+ (Graphics Device Interface Plus) technology, which is only available on Windows operating systems and also Microsoft has deprecated System.Drawing in newer versions of .NET Core and plans to eventually remove it completely

However, Instead of this,  you can try few alternative approaches to achieve image manipulation.

For instance, you can use `System.Drawing.Common` NuGet package or can use ImageSharp library for image processing tasks in ASP.NET Core applications.

Let's have a look how you can implement that:

You can, install `System.Drawing.Common` library.

[image]

After successful installation, you can use classes like Image, Bitmap, and Graphics from this package for basic image operations.

For instance:

```
using (var image = Image.FromStream(Upload.OpenReadStream()))
{
    using (var resizedImage = new Bitmap(image, new Size(newWidth, newHeight)))
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        resizedImage.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        await stream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you even can try `Imagesharp library`. In that scenario, you can do as following:

[image]

In case of ImageSharp, first of all, you should open the uploaded image using the [ImageSharp library](https://sixlabors.com/products/imagesharp/),
After that, you can resize the image using its width and height attribute. Finally, you can save the resized image to the file stream.

Let's have a look in practice how we can do that:

```
            var file = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "images", "DanceImages", Upload.FileName);

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create))
            {
               
                using (var image = Image.Load(Upload.OpenReadStream()))
                {
                   
                    var width = 300;
                    var height = 200;
                    image.Mutate(x => x.Resize(new ResizeOptions
                    {
                        Size = new Size(width, height),
                        Mode = ResizeMode.Max
                    }));

                    
                    image.Save(fileStream, new JpegEncoder());
                }
            }
```

**Note:** You can try the alternative approach in order to achieve your requirement. In addition, you could [refer to this official document for few more details.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/using-a-drawing-tool-image-editor-for-icons?view=msvc-170)

Comment: Well the question was can I use a Controller and View in a Razor Core .NET website to manipulate images. Looks like it might not be possible due to it only works on MS systems even though that is all I am going to use it on. 

I already tried System.Drawing.Common and it doesn't work. the word "Common" is underlined in red the using statement and "Image" and "Bitmap" are not available.

ImageSharp is too expensive for my use: $80 a month.
I will try ImageMagicK which is available in open source and $100 for purchase.
I will keep you posted. thanks

Comment: I see, thanks for your response. Yeah in that case ImageSharp or ImageMagicK  could be the option.

Comment: Thanks Md Farid. I am waiting for someone to reply to my Help post on ImageMagicK community forum because they don't have an example to resize an image uploaded by web browser. The example just resizes and image who's path is hard coded.